# Recover a image from USB Mac OS X

Tags: macos, usb

I have a image on a USB disk that I want to recover.

I've been trying a lot of free programs but when they recover the image, it can't be shown.

Is there some way I can byte recover this image or another way i can get this picture back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PhotoRec  http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec

the guide is here

http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step

Comment: The OP tried "a lot of freeware programs", how is PhotoRec different from/better than other recovery programs?

Comment: Because I went through many of these myself. As he has already figured out most of these are fairly limited in their abilities. PhotoRec, on the other hand, is extremely capable. If his image is even remotely recoverable this software will do it.

Comment: it just completed, but got some kind of an "harddrive", its inside my /Volumes/ dir, but cant find it.. its called recup_dir.1 how do i find this "file" and open it ? i tryed searching for it, but no luck

Comment: it should have asked you where to put the recovered files   http://www.cgsecurity.org/mw/images/PhotoRec_dst.png

Answer (score 1):

There are fewer freeware data recovery on Mac OS X than Windows. PhotoRec is definitely one that needs to be speak highly of. But it's a command line tool which may not be comfortable for general users. In your case, if the lost images lost from your USB is JPG format, you can also use Exif Untrasher (also freeware but few people know). Here is a review of those free ones on Mac OS X (truely freeware data recovery on Mac).

http://data-security-freeware.blogspot.com/2011/05/truly-free-mac-data-recovery-software.html

One more tip: if you can find a computer installed with Windows, things will be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Disk Drill can help you to recover deleted image, but it's not free. 
[http://download.cnet.com](http://download.cnet.com/Disk-Drill/3000-2094_4-75984417.html)

Unfortunately the free version only scans and you need to buy the pro version to recover your deleted files.

After mistakenly letting a Verbatim Media Share Mini wreck two HFS+ drives, Disk Drill's thorough deep scan recovered all the media files lost from two drives. It was amazing.